# where is more documentation about vino-server?

Tags: server, vnc

About vino-server, which pops up in my firewall, I found only little here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino

What is vino-server doing more else in VNC ? Is vino-server necessary, or can I leave vino-server out of my installation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vino is the VNC server for the GNOME desktop environment.

> A VNC server is a program that shares a desktop with other computers
>   over the Internet. You will need a VNC server if you want other people
>   to see your desktop. Every VNC server has different strengths and
>   weaknesses and is appropriate for different uses. This page will
>   discuss each of the VNC servers available in Ubuntu, and ways to
>   configure them for most common uses of VNC.

If you want to share a desktop with other computers over the Internet. You will need a VNC server

Vino Server [Mini Guide](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=194101)

Vino Server [Man Page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/vino-server/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Help</sup>

Comment: thx. this is what I have not found.

Comment: Glad that I can help:)

Comment: vino-server is a relict of company SUN ?

Comment: I don't think so.  Its Gnome.  see [Vino](https://wiki.gnome.org/Vino)

Comment: From the man page: `NOTES
       Written by Steven Zhang, Sun Microsystems Inc., 2006.

       Updated by Halton Huo, Sun Microsystems Inc., 2008.`

Comment: That man page is next to useless